# CS0426 when creating an object - How to understand error

Tags: c#, class, openxml, instantiation

I got a CS0426 compiler error when trying to open an Excel using `SpreadsheetDocument` class from `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` namespace.

I realized that this was because I was using `new` and, for some reason, the compiler didn't like it.

Why can't I create an instance of the object using `new`?

```
//Error CS0426
using (SpreadsheetDocument goldenFile = new SpreadsheetDocument.Open(goldenPath, true));

//Ok code
using (SpreadsheetDocument goldenFile = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(goldenPath, true));
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. If you want to use the method `Open()` from your `SpreadsheetDocument` class, you don't need to use `using`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by its name and context, the `SpreadsheetDocument.Open` method opens a new spreadsheet file for you to read/write from/to.

This should be the correct way to use this API:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument goldenFile = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(goldenPath, true)) {
    ...
}
```

You need to understand that not every class needs to be created by you writing the word `new` and directly calling the constructor. Sometimes, in this case for example, the instance of `SpreadsheetDocument` is probably created somewhere inside the `Open` method. The `Open` method simply *returns* the new instance, so that you can assign it to a variable (`goldenFile` in this case).

You can write a class that gets created with a static method too:

```
class Foo {
    // properties...

    // private constructor
    private Foo() { ... }

    public static GiveMeAFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }
}
```

I can now create an instance of `Foo` without directly using `new`:

```
var foo = Foo.GiveMeAFoo();
```

Something similar is happening inside `Open`.

---

The compiler gives off the error CS0426 because it thinks like this:

> I see that you are using the `new` operator, so you are creating a new instance of a type. What type is it that you are creating? Let's see... It's `SpreadsheetDocument.Open`! But wait a minute! That's not a type! I can't find a type called `Open` in `SpreadsheetDocument`!

Hence the error:

> The type name 'Open' does not exist in the type 'SpreadsheetDocument'.

Comment: Well, my question became another after edition, don't ask me why. I've got no feedback for that.
But in the original I wrote a fragment of the the class where you could see it has a protected constructor and a static Open like you showed here and that's probably what I wasn't understanding.
Thank you for your "compiler thinking" explanation, I'll try to use it for future cases.

Comment: The correct reason to why you don't need the `new` keyword is because the method Open is `static`

Comment: @Morgs The fundamental (but IMO not as helpful/useful) reason, is that `new` expects a type name (among other things) after it, which `SpreadsheetDocument.Open` is not (it's a method name). Whether or not the method is static is irrelevant, because I can't put `new` before an instance method either (`new MyInstanceMethod()`).

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because as is, when you're using new you essentially telling your code - "Create an object of a nested class 'Open'".
Either get rid of new or implement public constructor, and then call static Open method.

Answer (score 0):

The `Open` method is a static method which uses `new` in its implementation and returns an instance of `SpreadsheetDocument`. This is why you don't need to use `new`. Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.spreadsheetdocument.open?view=openxml-2.8.1).